# How to make canvas unmovable?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a tic-tac-toe sort of game, and the way it works is that the player will click on the screen to place an "x" or an "o". The code I use to determine where the "x" or "o" will be placed goes something like this:

```
mxpos = root.winfo_pointerx()
mypos = root.winfo_pointery()
zone = None
if mxpos > -1 and mxpos < 200:
    if mypos > -1 and mypos < 200:
        zone = 1
    if mypos > 199 and mypos < 400:
        zone = 2
    if mypos > 399 and mypos < 600:
        zone = 3
if mxpos > 199 and mxpos < 400:
    if mypos > -1 and mypos < 200:
        zone = 4
    if mypos > 199 and mypos < 400:
        zone = 5
    if mypos > 399 and mypos < 600:
        zone = 6
if mxpos > 399 and mxpos < 600:
    if mypos > -1 and mypos < 200:
        zone = 7
    if mypos > 199 and mypos < 400:
        zone = 8
    if mypos > 399 and mypos < 600:
        zone = 9
```

But this only works if the canvas is not moved because the coordinates of the mouse click are different then. I have looked up this several times and there seems to be no way to do this, but just asking if anyone has any way to get around this issue.

Comment: what means `if the canvas is not moved` ? Maybe you mean `if window is not move`. Maybe you should use coordinates from canvas, not from full screen/desktop.   Show minimal working example so we could run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind function to canvas then you should use values from `event` and then you can move window or canvas and you should get always the same values.

```
import tkinter as tk

def position(event):
    print('desktop:', root.winfo_pointerx(), root.winfo_pointery())
    print('canvas:', event.x, event.y)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', position)

root.mainloop()
```